# I've made two codes but I can't interpret why these two are different and produce different results

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

The first code that I made is this...

```
for (i = 0; startNum + i <= endNum; i++)
    {
        num = startNum + i; // num도 100부터 시작
        
        while (1) // 고집수를 확인하기 위함
        {
            doubleNum = transNumber(num); // 각 자리 수의 곱의 값
            count = count + 1;
            if (doubleNum < 10) {break;}
            
            num = doubleNum;
        }
```

The second code is the following

```
 for (i = 0; startNum + i <= endNum; i++){
        num = startNum + i; // num도 100부터 시작
        count = 0;
        while (num > 10) {
            num = transNumber(num);
            count++;
        }
    if (count == goNum)
        {
            printf("%d\n", startNum + i);
            count2 = count2 + 1;
        }
    }
```

What I thought is that if I make a new variable `doubleNum`, then it would keep taking in the result of `transNumber`. Also, since I put the `if statement`, then it would be the same code as the first code...

However, the results are clearly different, and I'm wondering if there could be a specific explanation for this?

Comment: The loops behave differently when the function `transNumber()` returns `10`. The loop in the first example does not end, but does in the second example.

Comment: ...but it is unclear which one is wrong, since the purpose is not known. Either the first one should be `doubleNum <= 10` or the second one should be `num >= 10`.

Comment: Although the first code is the one that brings out the proper outcome, do you reckon the other functions might have influence with the ```while statement``` bringing out the different output even though the two has the same function and works the same way after editing the ```<10``` to ```<=10``` or  ```>10``` in the second code?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
if (doubleNum < 10) {break;}
```

the cycle breaks when `doubleNum` reaches 9 or less.

In

```
 while (num > 10)
```

the cycle stops when `num` reaches 10 or less.

Hence the difference.

Using

```
while (num > 10) //first code

if (doubleNum <= 10) {break;} //second code
```

should fix it.

Comment: Then could I ask one more thing? I changed the ```doubleNum<10``` to ```doubleNum>10``` and ```doubleNum<=10``` and still there would be a different outcome... Would the two ```while statement``` codes still be different? Or would you reckon it is because of the other functions such as ```transNumber```?

Comment: @Learner_15, it's of course ver y different, `if(doubleNum<10)` means that the condition is true while doubleNum is lesser than 10, i.e. 9 or less, `if(doubleNum>10)` means the condition is true while doubleNum is larger that 10, i.e. 11 or more.